# Convert text YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS to Excel date

Tags: excel, date

I have a spreadsheet in Excel where in column, for example, B at the cell B5 and down there is a date entered in text format as YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS. I want to convert it in a such way that Excel will be able to recognize it as date, because then I need to use filters and so on.

I found [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/409896/how-do-i-enter-dates-in-iso-8601-date-format-yyyy-mm-dd-in-excel-and-have-exc?rq=1) and tried to do it as follows: go to Format Cells, select Date Category, change my locale to Australia, select YYYY-MM-DD, but it doesn't work.

Can anybody help me to convert all text dates in a selected column to Excel dates? Hours, minutes and seconds aren't very important.

Comment: What do you mean? It should recognize that as a date. Just change the formatting to say `yyyy/-mm-dd`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's what you need to do:

1. Make sure the cells with the text dates are formatted as **General**.
2. Use the DATEVALUE function to convert the text dates to Excel serial numbers. For example, if B5 has a YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS, then in cell D5 type:

> =DATEVALUE(B5)

3. Format cell D5 as a **Date**.

See also: [Convert Dates Stored as text to Dates](https://support.office.com/en-US/article/DATEVALUE-function-DF8B07D4-7761-4A93-BC33-B7471BBFF252) (Microsoft Office)

Answer (score 2):

since date format doesn't work, please try

right click>> format cells>>Category= custom>> type=d/mm/yyyy h:mm
If you do not want h:mm then just use type=d/mm/yyyy

Let me know how it goes.

Comment: I don't know why but after I selected desired type of date nothing changed. I solved it with DATEVALUE function.